# Word/phrase for "time-wise in-between"?

Tags: word-choice

Word/phrase for "time-wise in-between"?

Say my arrival was time-wise in-between lunch and dinner.

Say I want to say that more idiomatically, how would I do that?

Comment: Why wouldn't simply "between" work? Or possibly "in the middle of"

Comment: Between lunch and dinner is _in the afternoon_.

Answer (score 3):

Nicole is right; just use *between*. Most English speakers will easily distinguish between temporal and spatial uses of *between* without any additional words.

Answer (score 0):

Adding -wise to the end of a word, in general means "in terms of the thing preceding the "-wise".  I would think most often used when a distinction in what you are referring to is needed.

EXAMPLE: Someone asks you to describe the events of the previous night.  You could say, "food-wise, I tried the escargot". Time-wise, between eating and leaving the table, I got sick.

The whole thing "time-wise, in between", I have never really heard.  It seems that when followed by something that can be nothing other than a duration of time, it is better to leave out 'time-wise'.

Comment: He's not planning on using _time-wise_, he's just using that as the description of the word he's asking for.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of not thinking about this at all, I realized the word **interim** fits the criteria.

Although it's not terribly good from a stylistic perspective.